# Is there any way to cancel an in-progress upload in dojo?

Tags: dojo

I have a file uploader that handles very large files. Lots of times the users will cancel an upload. There does not appear to be any way to make the browser cancel the XHR POST that is handling it. Consequently, progress and complete events fire much later and the upload actually completes. Presumably there must be an XHR object embedded in the uploader somewhere that I could call abort on, but I see nothing in the API docs, or in a console dump of the uploader object.

Comment: Which specific file uploader (including version) are you using?

Comment: I'm using the HTML5 plugin of the Dojo 1.10.2 Uploader.

Comment: do you mean you use `dojox.form.Uploader` ? Or did you made your own uploader using `dojox.form.uploader._HTML5` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to support **only** the HTML5 uploader (and not the Iframe or the Flash version), then you can do something like that:

- Create a new uploader widget with the following (code not tested, might need some adjustment):

```js
define(['dojo/_base/declare', 'dojox/form/Uploader'], function(declare, Uploader) {
  return declare([Uploader], {
    xhrRequest: null,
    createXhr: function() {
      this.xhrRequest = this.inherited(arguments);
      return this.xhrRequest;
    },
    cancel: function() {
      if (this.xhrRequest && this.xhrRequest.abort) {
        this.xhrRequest.abort();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

- Use your new widget instead of `dojox.form.Uploader`
- Call the `cancel` method when you want to cancel the upload.

But remember: this will work **only** with the HTML5 uploader.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I don't have a lot of experience extending Dojo. Pretty sure I have the new Widget set up correctly, but I get "Cannot read property 'send' of undefined" when I start the upload on the selected file using the custom Widget. Any thoughts?

Comment: Got it. Two problems with the above code. I need to return the xhrRequest in createXhr, and the cancel method is called abort not cancel.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the answer

Comment: Thanks. I upvoted it, but apparently I'm not stack-overflow-y enough for it to count yet.

Comment: You need 15 of reputation I think. But you can mark you question aswered ;)